# How to best define a "contrast" in a Principal Component Analysis (PCA)?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, contrasts, eigenvalues

I have been studying how to interpret principal components.

I recently came across an example of a particular eigenvector:

$$e_j^T = \left[ \frac{\sqrt{2} }{2}, \frac{-\sqrt{2} }{2}, 0, \dots,0 \right]$$

I am under the impression that, often in social sciences, "this is called a contrast."

From what I can see, we have the difference between $X_1$ and $X_2$ (variables in our original dataset) playing a role in the $j$th eigenvector.

What can this say about the relationship between $X_1$ and $X_2$, with respect to this eigenvector?  There is clearly something going on with the equal, yet opposite, contribution of these independent variables, to our (possibly first) principal component.  I guess the answer to this is the answer to the question, "what is a contrast?"

Strangely enough, googling hasn't coming up with much of anything aside from dense discussion such as found on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Some corrections are needed to stave of possible confusion: first, $e_j^\prime$ is an eigenvector, not an eigenvalue. Second, it does not assert any relationship at all between $X_1$ and $X_2$: it is literally just a linear combination of the two. FWIW, googling "linear regression test contrast" turns up [the Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28statistics%29) right away.

Comment: argh, thanks, I've fixed my typos and generally cleaned up the question.

Comment: I'm confused...I was taught it's dangerous to interpret PCA components because they are not identifiable, only the subspace they span is identifiable.

Comment: @user43228 That's right. I think it's understood that $e_j^T$ is being considered only up to a nonzero multiple. The usual way to express it as a contrast would be as the vector $(1,-1,0,\ldots,0)$ or $(-1,1,0,\ldots,0)$. That is why Matt (the OP) is using terms like "equal, yet opposite contribution" without focusing on the magnitudes of the components.

Comment: @whuber I learned that they were not even identifiable modulo scalar multiple, because you get the same subspace by rotating your principal components.

Comment: @aabeshou A "rotation" is in that sense is not part of a PCA. A PCA finds eigenspaces and eigenvalues. The only rotation it can apply, without changing its results, would be an orthogonal transformation of orthonormalized basis elements of any subspace of dimension greater than one (which only rarely occurs). I suspect what you mean by "rotation" involves a *factor analysis* rather than a PCA.

Comment: @whuber I think this is probably going off into a different discussion about the interpretation of principal components, but what I mean is that PCA finds a low-dimensional (D) linear subspace that minimizes expected projection distance, and one choice of basis for that subspace is the first D eigenvectors, but it could be dangerous to interpret those vectors as anything but one possible basis for the _subspace_, which is what is identifiable and relevant.

That being said, I see that the eigenvectors are not totally arbitrary in that they point in directions of maximum variance.

Comment: @aabeshou Thank you for the clarification. That subspace is naturally graded into a flag, ordered by decreasing eigenvalue. This is what justifies referring to a first, second, third, *etc*, principal component. If the purpose is only to identify a subspace then indeed there are many more choices of basis. It's at that point, I believe, that other procedures such as factor analysis depart from PCA (and therefore ought to be distinguished from PCA as such).

Comment: @whuber Now we get back to the reason I brought this up: having agreed (if I understand you correctly) that we can't assign meaning to the components that come out of PCA, and that if we seek meaningful components we must turn to other methods, is it still reasonable to ask the question above about whether the component implies a negative relationship between X1 and X2? To answer my own question, I suppose it does still make sense because the component is still meaningful at least in the sense that it points in a direction of high variance in the set.

Comment: @aabeshou On the contrary, one *can* interpret individual PCA components (and this is often done). Nevertheless, I agree with your question and answer.

Answer (score 6):

Remembering that interpreting PCA results can be an art-form, let's use a relatively simple data set. [The link here](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~houldinb/Index/ST3011_files/ST3011slides4.pdf) shows a PCA and interpretation of Fisher's iris data, which you can easily obtain for yourself and analyse in the software of your choice.

The bottom of p.9 shows the eigenvalues for the four principal components and p.11 provides an interpretation of the first two principal components.

As you can see, **PC2 has been called a contrast** between sepal length/width and petal length/width. The reason for that is that the eigenvector values corresponding to the sepal measurements are all negative and those corresponding to the petal measurements are all positive. However, and this is where the PCA "art" interpretation comes into it, you could argue that petal width has little effect on PC2, as it is only 0.08 and therefore not a very large value.

Looking at PC3, and ignoring the fact it accounts for such little variance (as that is not the point of this discussion), it appears to be a contrast between sepal and petal width, on the one hand, and sepal length on the other.

Having a subject matter expert on hand to help interpret PCA results can be very useful.

Comment: +1 and I took the liberty of correcting what seemed a mistake/typo in one sentence, confusing eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Please check that this is indeed what you had in mind.